# How to generate PDF with different DPI using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, dpi

I need to generate two versions of PDF documents: with 300 dpi and width 150 dpi.

So I need to use different widths and heights of all elements, font sizes and use images with different width and height?

Or what should I do to generate PDF documents with different DPI?

Comment: have you tried the --dpi switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PDF with different dpi. I am not sure about command line arguments. If you are using php, you can try the KnpSnappy bundle. It has nice API and different options that can be configured.